# Can not debug using nuclide and react-create-scripts

Tags: reactjs, nuclide-editor

I'm using the [create react scripts](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

and have been unsuccessfully trying to debug using nuclide/atom. I have been using Chrome dev tools without problem up to this point.

In nuclide, I have tried attaching to each process which looked like the right one

[image]

and then set a break point in the my main components `render()` in atom. When I refresh the page in the browser, it just hangs.

Any thoughts are appreciated.